# enter triggers form submit when input (type submit) is disabled on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-submit

Recently I stumbled on another inconsistency between browsers.
On Chrome, in a form with the submit button disabled, pressing enter (in text input) will trigger submit. I created this simple page as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/andreitudor/s6EDX/1/

```
<form id="test" onSubmit="testForm()" >
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit" disabled="disabled" >
</form>
```

This also happens on IE9 (not that it matters), but it doesn`t happen on Firefox and Opera.

I think it is a bug in Chrome, but I might be wrong. This sort of behaviour can be very frustrating. Lets say we have an input that we want to validate (e. g. email address) before submitting. As a workaround for this issue we would have to move the validating logic to onSubmit function.

So, is this a bug? And how can we surpass this in a simple and elegant way? Maybe jQuery has a fix for this?!

Comment: It's not necessarily a bug, since it's normal for browsers to submit forms with just an text input on Enter. However that shouldn't be relevant for you, because even in that case the `onsubmit` should be called. Are you sure it isn't ? When I try it on your fiddle it is called.

Comment: It doesn`t trigger submit on firefox and opera (based on the js fiddle)

Comment: I don't have Opera, but on Firefox the fiddle doesn't submit at all when pressing enter. Are you sure you don't have any code that submits the form per Script (`form.submit()`)? Because that wouldn't trigger the submit handler.